# AndroidManifest.xml file not found - Android Studio 2.3 & React Native

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, react-native, android-studio-2.3

I am currently I am setting up a project with React Native and Android Studio (which I am new to) and followed the React Native setup guide down to the T.

Upon creating my SHA1 key for Google API Sign-in, I ran into an issue towards the end of the step-by-step process.

First, there was no output path defined. I navigated to Project Structure > Modules > and changed my selection from: "Inherit project compile output path", to: "Use module compile output path". This seems to fix that issue, but now I'm faced with: "Error:Android Source Generator: [ProjectName] AndroidManifest.xml file not found". How do I solve this? Do I need to manually create an "AndroidManifest.xml"?

I also noticed that my event log was telling me: "Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system." Do I need to migrate my project to Gradle? Will this help solving my issue?

Any help is much appreciate :)

Comment: how are you setting up your project? can you share some code? are you using react-native init or react-native-create?

Comment: if you look at the project in a JS editor, I was able to find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061034/how-to-generate-androidmanifest-xml-from-a-react-native-app-created-with-react-n